# Is it advisable to use $post->comment_count instead of get_comments_number( $post_id )

Tags: posts, functions, comments, variables, globals

I was learning from the WordPress codex about global variables and after

`var_dump($post)` I found out that `$post` has a property called `comment_count`

I was wondering whether I can directly use `$post->comment_count` instead of `get_comments_number( $post_id )` inside the loop? Or does it have any disadvantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is that classic question, do you have 6 eggs or half a dozen, and frankly, it doesn't actually matter.

It is however better to use [`get_comments_number()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments_number/) because

- the post object is retrieved from the `$GLOBALS['post']` global which is set by `the_post()` inside the loop
- the post object is validated through `WP_Post` (through [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/))
- the output from `get_comments_number()` is filterable should you later need to filter the output

Comment: I have trouble understanding the 2nd point. Can you explain me what does "the post object is validated through WP_Post" mean? What does validation mean here?

Comment: Check the source code for `get_post()` which I have linked to. Taking the post object through the `WP_Post` class, it makes sure that the post object is properly build and actually is a valid post object. This way, you are always sure that your post object is reliable

Comment: The filters in `get_comments_number()` are actually pretty important. Some third-party commenting systems may use that filter and `comments_number` to display the real comment count or a placeholder which is then filled dynamically with javascript.